# regex is missing expression

Tags: r

From the following text, I just need `mn12` but I am not getting it. With the first expression, I am getting `mn12` as well as `mn14`. I just need `mn12`.

please change the following with something. mn12 * operation 0010 to be mn14-f10

```
'\\b(m|s|x|p)(n|s|t)[[:alnum:]]{2}\\b')
'\\b(m|s|x|p)(n|s|t)[[:alnum:]]{2}[^-]\\b')
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your `[[:alnum:]]{2}` doesn't mean "any digit followed by 2".  It means "any sequence of two digits".

Is there a reason you're using [:alnum:] instead of `\\d` ?

If you're looking to capture `mn12` but not `mn14`, use

```
'\\b(m|s|x|p)(n|s|t)[[:alnum:]]2\\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the numeric number between 1-2. 
In general [1-9] captures numeric between 1 to 9, so in your case it will be [1-2]

```
'\\b(m|s|x|p)(n|s|t)[1-2]{2}\\b'
```

Comment: Numbers can be any numbers. it can ms79 , we can say first two are char and then next two are alphanumeric followed by space

Comment: use this then:'\\b(m|s|x|p)(n|s|t)[0-9]2\\b'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you need 2 lowercase characters followed by 2 digits, then it is simply, `\\b[a-z]{2}\\d{2}\\b`.